# Does a weighted Breadth First search have "memory" when moving to the next vertex?

Tags: graphs

I'm in a programming course and one Problem given to us is to mark the order in which BFS visits nodes in a weighted graph.

My question is whether BFS adds the distance of the previous path while adding a new vertex, as that will definitely change the order in which the vertices are added?

Comment: Standard BFS ignores edge weights. What are you asking?

Answer (score 5):

How about transforming your original graph to a graph with dummy nodes and just use regular BFS on it?

The idea is: if you have an edge with weight $k$ between $A$ and $B$, remove it. Then add a path between $A$ and $B$ with $k-1$ nodes in between, where all the edges have unit weight.

Now you can use regular BFS on your graph and it will reach the nodes in the same order as it would in the weighted version, without you having to transform the algorithm.

Ps. BFS always spreads out evenly, layer for layer like ripples in a pond. So if the next nodes to be added are A, B and C it will always add those nodes, but in which order does not matter- as long as the edges are unweighted.

Comment: The problem asked us to always choose the node with the least distance number first. I'm attaching an image to help you better visualize the problem. 
http://i.imgur.com/B1fC7.jpg

Comment: Then I'm keeping my answer as it answers your original q. :) But please update.

Comment: Therefore I know that BFDI are added first but do I then add A (using D because D to A is only 1 unit away) or do I add it using B because 11 + 12 = 23

Comment: If you are asked to implement BFS where you add nodes to the queue according to the cost of the edges from a node then you should choose A. Of course, this won't find the shortest path other than by fluke (in some graphs). Give us the exact wording of your question and we'll be able to answer you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but a fellow student explained it to me. I was understanding the question wrong. I've linked a picture of the problem above but it is in German.

It basically means doing BFS in the Lexicographic order (A<B<C...) and the cost of the edges don't play a role. Thank you so much for your time though.

Answer (score 3):

The weighted version of BFS is called [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). You can check the pseudocode in Wikipedia. Alternatively, Dijkstra's algorithm is supposed to find the shortest paths from the origin to all other vertices. If you've seen a proof in class, you should be able to match the algorithm to the proof. Only one implementation will result in the algorithm finding the shortest paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to do Dijkstra but I know that it uses a priority queue. In the problem it was stated that this algorithm uses a FIFO queue so it adds nodes like Prim's algorithm and it doesn't check back to see how big a distance the complete path is.

Comment: @user73142 I think Prim also uses a priority queue.